# Creation of azure_native frontdoor fails with "Frontdoor location must be global."

Tags: pulumi-azure

migrating my frontdoor from the to the `azure-native` package I am facing a strange error message that I cannot make sense of:

```
  azure-native:network:FrontDoor (frontDoor):
    error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Frontdoor location must be global."
```

I took almost 1 to 1 the example at `https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/network/frontdoor/` I only changed subId and  rg

For the record, I am migration to `azure-native` package because 1) it is advised and 2) I want to add waf policy and I was not able to do with the `azure.network` package.

Does that ring a bell?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the location must be set specifically to `global`. Something like

```
    location: "global",
```

I did not know of this location and it is not one of the values in the location enumeration.